# Get Azure virtual machine status

Tags: c#, azure

Any help, how I can get virtual machines current status?

[image]

I've tried these, but I cannot get example status "Stopped".

```
Console.WriteLine(role.RoleName);
//Console.WriteLine(role.ResourceExtensionReferences[0].State);
//Console.WriteLine(deployment.RoleInstances[0].PowerState);
//Console.WriteLine(client.Deployments.GetBySlot("demovm", DeploymentSlot.Production).Status);
```

Any clues/ideas, what I'm missing?

Comment: have a look at this link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.aspx) `RoleEnviroment: Provides information about the configuration, endpoints, and status of running role instances.` may point you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you, however it did not resolve my problem. I can see only if virtual machine is "busy". So, I still get the "wrong status"...

Answer (score 3):

You would use the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460806.aspx

Ensure embed-detail is true and you'll get a list of all nodes within the cloud service.

```
  <RoleInstanceList>
    <RoleInstance>
      <RoleName>name-of-role</RoleName>
      <InstanceName>name-of-role-instance</InstanceName>
      <InstanceStatus>status-of-role-instance</InstanceStatus>
      <InstanceUpgradeDomain>update-domain-of-role-instance</InstanceUpgradeDomain>
      <InstanceFaultDomain>fault-domain-of-role-instance</InstanceFaultDomain>
      <InstanceSize>size-of-role-instance</InstanceSize>
      <InstanceStateDetails>state-of-role-instance</InstanceStateDetails>
      <InstanceErrorCode>error-code-returned-for-role-instance</InstanceErrorCode>
      <IpAddress>ip-address-of-role-instance</IpAddress>
      <InstanceEndpoints>
        <InstanceEndpoint>
          <Name>name-of-endpoint</Name>
          <Vip>virtual-ip-address-of-instance-endpoint</Vip>
          <PublicPort>public-facing-port-of-instance-endpoint</PublicPort>
          <LocalPort>internal-facing-port-of-instance-endpoint</LocalPort>
          <Protocol>protocol-of-instance-endpoint</Protocol>
        </InstanceEndpoint>
      </InstanceEndpoints>
      <PowerState>state-of-role-instance</PowerState>
      <HostName>dns-name-of-service</HostName>
      <RemoteAccessCertificateThumbprint>cert-thumbprint-for-remote-access</RemoteAccessCertificateThumbprint>
    </RoleInstance>
  </RoleInstanceList>
```

You have `InstanceStatus` and `PowerState` to choose from depending on what you're looking for. Not the most intuitive place to look I agree.

Comment: Thank you Matt, however I cannot use that solution. Because I have 2 virtual machines in same Azure Cloud service. If one of my virtual machines is stopped and another is running, I don't get that information. Any another solution? Thanks.

Comment: Hm.. that's odd. I use the same call to parse the status of all my VMs. It'll show the list regardless of if the VM is running or stopped. It'll even show StoppedDeallocated. You're basically grabbing  the Cloud Service properties and iterating through the RoleInstanceList which has all your servers in it. If you want to find a stopped one you'd look for StoppedVM.

I implemented this using Python for the Azure Libcloud Compute driver I wrote. You can reference it here: [Libcloud](https://github.com/baldwinSPC/libcloud/blob/LIBCLOUD-556_azure_compute_driver/libcloud/compute/drivers/azure.py)