# Azure resource management API not showing virtual machine state?

Tags: c#, api, azure

So I've been poking around at read-only api access into azure with the resource management api. Right now I'm focusing on Virtual Machines. I've been using this pre-release package with TokenCredentials:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute/13.0.1-prerelease

I get a bunch of rich info about my vms but I'm missing a pretty criticle piece of data and that's whether the vm is on or off. I've found a couple of meta data properties like InstanceView and Plan to be null when I expected them to be populated. It may because of how I launched my vms, it may be a unfinished or buggy new package, I can't tell. I was thinking InstanceViews statues would tell me what state the vm is in.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.virtualmachineinstanceview.aspx

So I suppose I have to look elsewhere. I did find this older stackoverflow question that may be what I'm looking for:

[azure management libraries virtual machine state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317281/azure-management-libraries-virtual-machine-state)

However I'm not sure what dll this GetAzureDeyployment is part of or if it's even TokenCredential compatible. Anyone know whats up?

Comment: That GetAzureDeyployment is for ASM, while you are using ARM. Hence, the Stack Overflow question is not suitable for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following c# code to get the power status of your VM.

```
using System;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Rest;

namespace GetVmARM
{
    class Program
    {

        private static String tenantID = "<your tenant id>";
        private static String loginEndpoint = "https://login.windows.net/";
        private static Uri redirectURI = new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");
        private static String clientID = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2";
        private static String subscriptionID = "<your subscription id>";
        private static String resource = "https://management.core.windows.net/";



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var token = GetTokenCloudCredentials();
            var credential = new TokenCredentials(token);
            var computeManagementClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credential);
            computeManagementClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionID;

            InstanceViewTypes expand = new InstanceViewTypes();

            var vm = computeManagementClient.VirtualMachines.Get("<the resource group name>", "<the VM>", expand);

            System.Console.WriteLine(vm.InstanceView.Statuses[1].Code);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to continue");
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static String GetTokenCloudCredentials(string username = null, SecureString password = null)
        {
            String authString = loginEndpoint + tenantID;

            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);

            var promptBehaviour = PromptBehavior.Auto;

            var userIdentifierType = UserIdentifierType.RequiredDisplayableId;

            var userIdentifier = new UserIdentifier("<your azure account>", userIdentifierType);

            var authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientID, redirectURI, promptBehaviour, userIdentifier);

            return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see in this piece of code, I am using InstanceViewTypes which is not available in the document. This is new in the 13.0.1 pre-release version. But yes, if you adding this to your computeManagementClient.VirtualMachines.Get method, you will be able to get extra information for your VM.

Furthermore, I am using vm.InstanceView.Statuses[1] because vm.InstanceView.Statuses[0] is the ProvisioningState. And, I am not sure if the order is always like this, so you may need to loop through the whole status list.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much. 

That's very strange usage on microsofts part. Why does a Get populate the Status but not List? It's using the same class in both cases so you'd assume it's the same. hmmm ah well.